# calculating the difference of the sum of two different columns from two tables

Tags: mysql

i have three different tables named as CASHIER, SALES, and REFUNDS

CASHIER table has:

> cashierID / cashier_name

SALES table has:

> salesID / cashierID / amountReceived

REFUNDS table has:

> refundsID / cashierID / amountRefunded

i want to display the total amount of the cashiers received from sales and refunds via amountReceived and amountRefunded columns respectively. will there be a mysql syntax for that? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.cashier_name AS cashier, 
    COALESCE( salesByCashier.totalSales, 0 ) AS sales,
    COALESCE( refundsByCashier.totalRefunded, 0 ) AS refunds,
    COALESCE( salesByCashier.totalSales, 0 ) - 
      COALESCE( refundsByCashier.totalRefunded, 0  ) AS total
FROM
  cashier c
LEFT JOIN
   ( SELECT s.cashierID AS cashierID, SUM(amountReceived) AS totalSales
     FROM sales s
     GROUP BY s.cashierID ) salesByCashier
ON c.cashierID = salesByCashier.cashierID
LEFT JOIN
   ( SELECT r.cashierID AS cashierID, SUM(amountRefunded) AS totalRefunded
     FROM refunds r
     GROUP BY r.cashierID ) refundsByCashier
ON c.cashierID = refundsByCashier.cashierID
```

Comment: i think this is it! thanks a lot.

but can i ask a question, whats the meaning of COALESCE (field 1, 0)?

Comment: You get 0 instead of NULL from LEFT JOIN if a cashier sold nothing or nothing was returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    c.cashierID,
    c.cashier_name,
    sum(s.amountReceived) as totalReceived,
    sum(r.amountRefunded) as totalRefunded
from CASHIER c
left join SALES s on s.cashierID = c.cashierID
left join REFUNDS r on r.cashierID = c.cashierID
group by 1,2
```

Comment: +1. Beat me by slightly more than a mouseclick. (Funny; it even included the same choice of aliases for the tables.) :)

Comment: sir would you mind if i ask this question? In your group by clause which 1 and 2, what do you mean by that? do you group it with the first column and the second column?

Comment: @johntotetwoo `GROUP BY 1,2` is SQL standard abbreviation meaning `GROUP BY <COLUMN #1>, <COLUMN #2>`, ie in this case having exactly the same meaning as `GROUP BY c.cashierID, c.cashier_name` . Many people don't like this, but I find it far, far easier to read and maintain. btw, you can list as many column numbers as you like in whatever order you like

Comment: I suggest you test your query for 1 cashier, his 2 sales and 1 refund. You'll double his refund.

Comment: @piotrm yes, it multiplied my totalAmount by how many rows present in the REFUNDS table.